# How to type function that converts array to object indexed by a key in array's elements in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type a relatively simple seven line JavaScript function. It takes a string and an array and then returns an object where the keys of the object are elements' values for the key and the values of the object are the elements.

```
function indexBy(key, elements) {
  const result = {}
  for(let element of elements) {
    result[element[key]] = element
  }
  return result
}
```

So

```
const elements = [{id: 1, name: 'alice'}, {id: 2, name: 'bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'charlie'}]
indexBy('name', elements)
```

would produce:

```
{alice: {id: 1, name: 'alice'}, bob: {id: 2, name: 'bob'}, charlie: {id: 3, name: 'charlie'}
```

I was able to get one solution using a type guard:

```js
function indexBy<S extends keyof T, T>(key: S, elements: T[]) {
  const result: {[key: string]: T} = {}
  for(let element of elements) {
    const value = element[key] 
    if(typeof value === 'string') {
      const str: string = value
      result[str] = element
    } else {
      throw new Error('element in array cannot be indexed by key since key is not a string')
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

However, it would be better if I could get the compiler to generate an error message instead of throwing one at runtime (and also avoid the slight performance hit from checking every element). Using the example input above, I would like if `indexBy('id', elements)` produced a compiler error since the values of `id` for the elements are numbers not strings.

Is it possible?

Comment: hope you know that you can convert the number to string and use it as a key

Comment: @PranoySarkar Even better: you can just use numbers as keys in TypeScript/JavaScript objects. `{100: 200}` is a perfectly valid object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your type `T` extend a `Record` with `S` as the key type and `string` as the value type:

```
function indexBy<S extends keyof T, T extends Record<S, string>>(key: S, elements: T[]) {
  const result: {[key: string]: T} = {};
  for(let element of elements) {    
    result[element[key]] = element;
  }
  return result;
}

const correct = [{id: 1, name: 'alice'}, {id: 2, name: 'bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'charlie'}];
indexBy('name', correct); // works

const incorrect =  [{id: 1, name: 1000}, {id: 2, name: 'bob'}, {id: 3, name: 'charlie'}];
indexBy('name', incorrect); // compilation error
```

The `correct` array will work as expected, while the `incorrect` array will result in the following compilation error:

```
Argument of type '({ id: number; name: number; } | { id: number; name: string; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"name", string>[]'.
  Type '{ id: number; name: number; } | { id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"name", string>'.
    Type '{ id: number; name: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"name", string>'.
      Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```